# Most frequently overlapping range - Python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, overlap

I'm a beginner, trying to write code listing the most frequently overlapping ranges in a list of ranges.

So, input is various ranges (#1 through #7 in the example figure; https://prntscr.com/kj80xl) and I would like to find the most common range (in the example 3,000- 4,000 in 6 out of 7 - 86 %). Actually, I would like to find top 5 most frequent.

Not all ranges overlap. Ranges are always positive and given as integers with 1 distance (standard range).

What I have now is only code comparing one sequence to another and returning the overlap, but after that I'm stuck.

```
def range_overlap(range_x,range_y):
    x = (range_x[0], (range_x[-1])+1)
    y = (range_y[0], (range_y[-1])+1)

    overlap = (max(x[0],y[0]),min(x[-1],(y[-1])))
    if overlap[0] <= overlap[1]:
        return range(overlap[0], overlap[1])
    else:
        return "Out of range"
```

I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Better solution

I came up with a simpler solution (at least IMHO) so here it is:

```
def get_abs_min(ranges):
    return min([min(r) for r in ranges])


def get_abs_max(ranges):
    return max([max(r) for r in ranges])


def count_appearances(i, ranges):
    return sum([1 for r in ranges if i in r])


def create_histogram(ranges):
    keys = [str(i) for i in range(len(ranges) + 1)]
    histogram = dict.fromkeys(keys)
    results = []
    min = get_abs_min(range_list)
    max = get_abs_max(range_list)

    for i in range(min, max):
        count = str(count_appearances(i, ranges))

        if histogram[count] is None:
            histogram[count] = dict(start=i, end=None)

        elif histogram[count]['end'] is None:
            histogram[count]['end'] = i

        elif histogram[count]['end'] == i - 1:
            histogram[count]['end'] = i

        else:
            start = histogram[count]['start']
            end = histogram[count]['end']
            results.append((range(start, end + 1), count))
            histogram[count]['start'] = i
            histogram[count]['end'] = None

    for count, d in histogram.items():
        if d is not None and d['start'] is not None and d['end'] is not None:
            results.append((range(d['start'], d['end'] + 1), count))

    return results


def main(ranges, top):
    appearances = create_histogram(ranges)
    return sorted(appearances, key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)[:top]
```

The idea here is as simple as iterating through a superposition of all the ranges and building a histogram of appearances (e.g. the number of original ranges this current `i` appears in)

After that just sort and slice according to the chosen size of the results.

Just call main with the ranges and the top number you want (or `None` if you want to see all results).

## OLDER EDITS BELOW

I (almost) agree with @Kasramvd's answer.

here is my take on it:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

def range_overlap(x, y):
    common_part = list(set(x) & set(y))
    if common_part:
        return range(common_part[0], common_part[-1] +1)
    else:
        return False

def get_most_common(range_list, top_frequent):
    overlaps = Counter(range_overlap(i, j) for i, j in 
         combinations(list_of_ranges, 2))
    return [(r, i) for (r, i) in  overlaps.most_common(top_frequent) if r]
```

you need to input the `range_list` and the number of `top_frequent` you want.

## EDIT

the previous answer solved this question for all 2's combinations over the range list.

This edit is tested against your input and results with the correct answer:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

def range_overlap(*args):
    sets = [set(r) for r in args]
    common_part = list(set(args[0]).intersection(*sets))
    if common_part:
        return range(common_part[0], common_part[-1] +1)
    else:
        return False

def get_all_possible_combinations(range_list):
    all_combos = []
    for i in range(2, len(range_list)):
        all_combos.append(combinations(range_list, i))
    all_combos = [list(combo) for combo in all_combos]
    return all_combos


def get_most_common_for_combo(combo):
    return list(filter(None, [range_overlap(*option) for option in combo]))


def get_most_common(range_list, top_frequent):
    all_overlaps = []
    combos = get_all_possible_combinations(range_list)
    for combo in combos:
        all_overlaps.extend(get_most_common_for_combo(combo))
    return [r for (r, i) in  Counter(all_overlaps).most_common(top_frequent) if r]
```

And to get the results just run `get_most_common(range_list, top_frequent)`

Tested on my machine (ubunut 16.04 with python 3.5.2) with your input `range_list` and `top_frequent = 5` with the results:

```
[range(3000, 4000), range(2500, 4000), range(1500, 4000), range(3000, 6000), range(1, 4000)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This seems to be a good solution, but both your and Kasramvd's code seems to be slightly off, and I can't figure out why.

I tried entering the ranges from the previously linked example: https://textuploader.com/d7qjk

All counts seem to be 1 too low, which of course is easy to fix if it is systematic. What is however strange, and that I can't figure out, is that the code doesn't return range 3000;4000 (count 6), which is supposed to be the most frequent one. Neither does it return range 2500:3000 or 8000,9000 (tied second).
Printscreen of output: http://prntscr.com/kjaln8

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! 

Edit: However, 8000,9000 (count 4) should show up before 1,4000 (count 3).

Comment: Absolutely amazing what commitment you have to helping a complete stranger on the internet! Even though I only understand about half of the code, I too would agree the approach seems simpler.
I do however see a problem which I hope can be resolved by modifying the code slightly. Consider a rangelist with three ranges: (1, 100) (1,40) and (30,70). The code correctly gives the answer 30,40 count 3, but crops the answer for the n=2 counts. Instead of 1,40 it gives 1,30, and instead of 30,70 it gives 40,70. Could this easily be resolved.

Again, many thanks!!

Comment: Thats because 30-40 has n=3 so for n=2 you have 1-30 and 40-70

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense. I didn't realize the top counted ranges are excluded from the following counts. I think that suits my purpose well. I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can first change your function to return a valid range in both cases so that you can use it in a set of comparisons. Also, since Python's `range` objects are not already created iterables but smart objects that only get `start`, `stop` and `step` attributes of a range and create the range on-demand, you can do a little change on your function as well.

```
def range_overlap(range_x,range_y):
    rng = range(max(range_x.start, range_y.start),
                min(range_x.stop, range_y.stop)+1)
    if rng.start < rng.stop:
        return rng.start, rng.stop
```

Now, if you have a set of ranges and you want to compare all the pairs you can use `itertools.combinations` to get all the pairs and then using `range_overlap` and `collections.Counter` you can find the number of overlapped ranges.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

overlaps = Counter(range_overlap(i,j) for i, j in 
             combinations(list_of_ranges, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you!! Please see my answer to bergerg. A similar problem occur when I use your code, but with slightly different output: http://prntscr.com/kjaq4j